# HIVE: UDF Error FAILED: Class <ClassName> not found

Tags: hadoop, jar, hive, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to use myjar.jar as UDF function in HIVE as follows,

```
echo "Add myjar.jar"
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -e "ADD JAR  /gpfs/user/username/HIVE/myjar.jar;"

echo "List myjar.jar, this is showing local directory path"
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -e "list jar;"


$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -e "drop function if exists myfunction;"

echo "Create temporary function, my class name is UpperCase"

$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -e "CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION myfunction AS 'Upper.UpperCase';"

$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -e "SELECT myfunction(line) FROM doc where line='COCO';"
```

But I'm getting following error,

```
FAILED: Class Upper.UpperCase not found
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask
```

I doubt that the problem could be that my jars are not copied to local node directory. But I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ADD JAR` is only applicable to the session that it is run in - but in your case you are running a new session for each statement. Instead you should put all of the statements in a single script and call it similarly to:

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -f yourscript.sql
```